Man who can't tell right from wrong gets experimental surgery
In the part of the film I'm thinking about there's an older man who can't tell right from wrong, while imprisoned for I can't even remember what, they do an experimental surgery to try and replace the part of his brain that can tell right from wrong and the movie continues with him protecting a little girl I think?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Is this Criminal (2016)...?
According to a review, the main character, Jericho Stewart, was a prisoner with damaged frontal lobes, rendering him unable to tell right from wrong. The CIA transplant the memories of Bill Pope -- a recently-deceased agent -- onto him so that he can complete Pope's mission.

Jericho Stewart (Kevin Costner) is a lifelong criminal who is a true sociopath and psychopath. Due to an accident as a child, his frontal lobes were damaged, so he literally has no way to tell right from wrong or what human emotions are like. Luckily for him, his prison sentence is cut short as he is needed by the CIA to be a human guinea pig for a memory transplant experiment. Before being killed in the field, Agent Bill Pope (Ryan Reynolds) hid the dangerous hacker, the Dutchman (Michael Pitt), whose newest virus can control the entire military might of the United States. CIA chief, Quaker Wells (Gary Oldman) needs Jericho to use Pope’s memories to find the Dutchman before the mustache-twirling terrorist, Hagbardaka Heimbahl (Jordi Molla) does. Jericho escapes CIA custody and heads out on his own vendetta to gain a fortune and find his freedom along the way.

According to the Wikipedia page, Stewart subsequently meets Pope's widow and daughter, Jillian and Emma, and ends up saving them from the film's antagonist.

Jerico retreats to the Pope's house, where he encounters Jillian and explains the situation to her. Although she initially fears him, Jillian comes to accept Jerico as she sees him bonding with her daughter, Emma, allowing Jerico to stay the night.




